# Приведение типа в шаблонном классе

Tags: c++

```
class A{};
class B : public A {};

template<typename T>
class X {};

template<typename T>
class Y : public X<T> {};

(X<A>)Y<B>;
```

Последняя строка утверждает, что преобразование недопустимо. Хотя вроде бы даже для одного типа класса, но разных типов в шаблоне та же проблема.

Суть вопроса, вроде как, в приведении типа в шаблоне.

```
(X<A>)X<B>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

К сожаленю шаблоны языка C++, инстанцированные разными, пусть даже связанными в одну иерархию наследования, типами, между сабой никак не связаны: один не будет наследником другого, так же не будет сгенерирована функция приведения от одного шаблона к другому.

Если вам действительно нужно преобразовывать `X<B>` к `X<A>`, то можно написать свою функцию преобразования:

```
class A {}; class B : public A {};

template<typename T> class X {
  public:
    X(T value) : value_(value) {}

    template<typename U>
    operator X<U> () const {
      return X<U>(value_);
    }

  private:
    T value_;
};

int main() {
  X<A> xa = X<B>(B());
}
```

На самом же деле, то что вам нужно это [ковариантные шаблоны](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29). В С++ шаблоны *инвариантны*, язык Scala предоставляет больше возможностей для параметризации:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

class X[+T] {} // covariant
class Y[-T] {} // contravariant
class Z[T] {} // invariant like in C++

val x : X[A] = new X[B]() // OK, X -- ковариантный
//val y1 : Y[A] = new Y[B]() // не скомпилируется
val y2 : Y[B] = new Y[A]() // Здесь работает наоборот, Y -- контравариантный
//val z : Z[A] = new Z[B]() // Тоже не скомпилируется, здесь как в C++
```

Answer (score 2):

А это разные типы, нечего тут преобразовывать. Можете считать, что параметр шаблона формирует имя шаблонного класса `X`, если Вам так будет понятнее. И этот параметр не имеет свойств наследования :) Кроме того, такое преобразование даже для досягаемых типов неверно. В таком случае потребуется `static_cast`.
 --
Вот если бы `X<T>` наследовался от `T`, тогда был бы другой разговор.